# Unable to start standalone-full-ha.xml file in jboss eap7... Is there any changes i have to do before starting the profile?

Tags: jboss, middleware, jboss-eap-7

I used the command `./standalone.sh -c standalone-full-ha.xml` to start the profile in jboss eap 7.. but it is not starting and I am unable to find the bug as there is no any error regarding this.. can anyone help me???

Answer (score 0):

There is no change needs to be done for starting JBoss in full-ha profile using standalone-full-ha.xml file. Make sure you are running EAP 7 with JDK 8.